# Zendesk Java client API updating CustomFieldValue

Tags: java, api, client, cloudbees, zendesk

I am having trouble figuring out how to correctly update a custom field using Zendesk Java client API, and I the problem is I am unsure of the syntax of the command.

I'm able to update comments using the `zendesk.createComment()`, tags, and other fields but just cannot figure out the syntax for custom fields.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Zendesk zd = new Zendesk.Builder(url)
        .setUsername(uid)
        .setPassword(pwd)
        .build();
}


private static void setComment(Zendesk zd, long inTicket, String inComment) {
    Comment cmt = new Comment();
    cmt.setBody(inComment);
    cmt.setPublic(pubPriv);
    zd.createComment(inTicket, cmt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The custom field update can be accomplished using the following example:

```
/*
 When a customer ftps a file to TCS we need to update the ZenDesk ticket
 with the file information. The file name is stored in the AddAttachment List
 custom field. This is a destructive field so it must be read first and the
 new data concatenated after a line feed then re-written.
 1) Read current field data
 2) Concatenate line feed and new data onto old data
 3) Write new field data
*/
long fieldNum = 25326406;
showDebug("In addAttachmentList");
Ticket ticket = zd.getTicket(inTicket);
List<CustomFieldValue> cfvl = ticket.getCustomFields();
for (int i = 0; i < cfvl.size(); i++) {
    if (cfvl.get(i).getId() == fieldNum) {
        showDebug("Original value: " + cfvl.get(i).getValue());
        cfvl.get(i).setValue(cfvl.get(i).getValue() + "\n" + inComment);
        cfvl.get(i).setId(fieldNum);
        ticket.setCustomFields(cfvl);
        showDebug("After Update value: " + cfvl.get(i).getValue());

        zd.updateTicket(ticket);
    }
}
```